# infinite scrolling GET request

Tags: php, pagination, infinite-scroll

I am using jQuery infinite scrolling which loads a couple hundred results from a MySQL request.  I have some pagination set up and the URL for the next button looks something like,

```
<a title='>' href="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?view=a&b=5&pagenumber=$nextpage>
```

when I use

```
$page=$_GET['pagenumber'];
echo $page;
```

The GET request only works on the first page.  The next page of results can't find the GET request when loaded via infinite scroller.  I have tried typing in the URL manually and then the GET request works for page 2.  So something is happening when infinite scroll retrieves the results for the next set of items.  I have been unable to pinpoint it and curious if anyone can help me with this.

The page number is important of course because MySQL results depend on it.

Comment: For one thing, I suggest you change this `<a title='>'` to `<a title='&gt;'` - that risks in putting a damper on things.

Comment: This line `href="{ echo$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}` I'm not sure about. If it's outside your PHP tags, you'll most probably need to do this  `href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Comment: That was merely an example.  But I am curious why you mentioned it, how could that put a damper on things?

Comment: @SLIM because it can treat as a closing tag for anchor

Comment: Putting a `>` inside PHP is most likely to cause trouble, since PHP uses that character in more ways than one.

Comment: I am so glad I asked this question, because you just helped me indirectly realize I had a typo in my URL!  I had the correct format but my ?view= was a reference to another view.  Thank you!  And now I realize I should have checked closer before asking the question.  And thanks for the little tidbit about '>'.

Comment: @SLIM You're welcome. That's what we're here for ;-)